# Проблема при подключении к MySql DB через Tomcat realm и JDBC Driver

Tags: java, tomcat

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root;password=plemia000'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
      driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coupon_system?user=root;password=plemia000"
      userTable="user" userNameCol="nickname" userCredCol="password"
      userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role"/>
```

- Не могу понять в чём дело! Не понятна сама ошибка **"using password:NO" ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите пароль для пользователя `root` используя консоль

```
mysqladmin -u root password qwertyuiop123
```

Comment: "mysql is not recognized as internal or external command" ошибка в консоле

Comment: Вы запускаете команду с правами администратора?

Comment: Да. Теперь получаю тоже самое в самом MySql  - на этот раз using password:YES

Comment: Еще необходимо дать права   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%password%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: Где я это пишу ???

Comment: Сначала зайдите в MySQL mysql --user=root mysql 
а потом введите команду